# Git checkout to first commit

Tags: git

How do I list all of my git branches after checking out my first commit?

For example

```
git log --oneline
```

displays all of my branches:

```
06c4b5c Version 3 of Hello World
efa167f Version 2 of Hello World
47a33c8 Hello World
```

If I check out my first commit

```
git checkout 47a33c8
```

this message is displayed

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
>   another checkout...

then if I do this:

```
git log --oneline
```

only the first commit is displayed now:

> 47a33c8 Hello World

My question is, if I did not know the location of HEAD was at 06c4b5c originally, how do I return to this location after checking out the first commit?

Also, I get this error

> Error: pathspce '06c4b5c' did not match any file(s) known to git.

when i try to checkout 06c4b5c

```
git checkout 06c4b5c
```

Comment: For your second problem, try checking it out by its full commit hash (in `git log`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to see where you were before. You'll see an entry like

```
checkout: moving from master to 47a33c8
```

Just do `git checkout master` to return to that branch.

To list all the branches, use `git branch -l`.